# Fluidpage: Error when extending an extbase model

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

I was trying to extend tx_news with some extra fields and was getting an error so I installed this extension to see if that worked: https://github.com/cyberhouse/t3ext-newsauthor

I get the same error on the news pages with my extension and the reference extension:

> Sorry, the requested view was not found.
>
> The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be
>   resolved for action "error" in class
>   "Tx_Fluidpages_Controller_PageController".

and the following errors in the be log:

> Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename
>   cannot be empty in
>   /var/www/ukcg6/typo3_src-6.1.7/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/View/TemplateView.php
>   line 187

I am using Typo3 6.1 with:

- Fluidpages 2.1.0
- Fluidcontent 3.1.0
- Flux 6.0.3
- VHS 1.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to setup your stack here now, but I'll try to help with some general advice on how to trace and locate such kinds of errors.

---

Basically you will need to trace the error back from the TemplateView.php line 187.

Starting there you look for the variable which is the filename. You can var_dump() that variable and it will probably be "null".

Then you follow that variable back to its origin in backwards order. That means each time this variable gets passed you search for the place in the source code where the function *which gets it as a parameter* is called.

Doing this you'll definitely find the point where something goes wrong. The filename variable is not properly set and that means one of the previously called functions which should set it screwed up.